rttm files generated by diart.stream, are only speaker0 and speaker1
I use https://github.com/juanmc2005/diart for realtime speaker dizrization.
When I run :
diart.stream input.wav --tau-active=0.555 --rho-update=0.422 --delta-new=1.517 --hf-token  --output rttm_folder --no-plot, in generated rttm file only get **speaker0 **and **speaker1 **even though there are 7 speakers.
It does not depend on audio, always get only 2 speakers.
Hyperparameters are taken from DIHARD III dataset:
tau (0.555) rho(0.422)  delta(1.517)
I tried  diart.stream -h to find if it contains parameter related the count of speakers, but there is no such parameter.

I specified different --delta parameters 1.0, 0.95, 0.98 etc. and now it generates more than 2 speaker labels
